# Create contentcontrol in code behind

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

How to create following Border with contentcontrol in code?

```
<Border Name="Test">
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource _cardDataTemplate}" Content="{Binding}"/>
</Border>
```

I am using following code, but the datatemplate is not applied:

```
Border newCard = new Border();
newCard.Child = new ContentControl()
{
    ContentTemplate = CardDataTemplate
};
```

CardDataTemplate is assigned, and is not the problem as far as I know.

Comment: datatemplates consist of factories, not of controls. Check the FrameworkElementFactory (and connected classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to create a binding for the Content property to DataContext ( `Content="{Binding}"` in XAML). You can do it by writing the following code:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(yourContentControlInstance, ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding());
```

Comment: thank you!! I searched all day for a solution to this problem. In my case the template was applied but the binding was not working. Is it so difficult to find information about this because there is a better way of instantiating templates from code?